# Selenium IDE - storedVars exception

Tags: regex, match, selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE and i want to store a data:

```
storeEval | storedVars['varRate'].match(/EUR.\d+.\d+/); |rate01
echo |${rate01}     
storeEval |storedVars['rate01'].match(/\d+.\d/);|rate
```

The first one works just fine but second one throws an exception:

> **[error] Threw an exception: storedVars.rate.match is not a function**

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget that the metacharacter `.` in a regex will match any character. If you intent to match the `.` character, escape it in your regex like this: `\.`.

Comment: In first line: first dot match space and second dot match a dot. I know I could have used something else but that wasn't the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Did you try using a different name than the variable in storedVars?
Maybe use storedVars['rate_01'] to avoid conflicts with the rate01 variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that match is a string method and I didn't use it correctly. First result was an array so i added another comand to cast it to string:
    `store  | ${rate01}  |  rate02` followed by 
    `storeEval |  storedVars['rate02'].match(/\d+.\d/);|  rate`